# Count rows by category using where clause in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using custom cursor adapter to get catagories in listview from SQlite view and also want to show specific rows count saved with same category name.i try many times but unfortuntely can't succeed.

here the Query which i used

```
int GetTasksCountByCategory(String cat)
 {

     Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  ViewTasks where Category_name = "+"'"+"cat"+"'", null);
     int x = 0;
     if (cur.moveToFirst())
     {
         x = cur.getInt(0);
     }

        cur.close();
        return x;    
 }
```

and my Adapter class

```
public class cursorAdapter2 extends CursorAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    DbAdapter myAdapter = new DbAdapter(mContext);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public cursorAdapter2(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext=context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(arg2.getContext());
         View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, arg2, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLastcatId);
        category.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME)));

         String getCat = (String) category.getText();
           int i = myAdapter.GetTasksCountByCategory(getCat);
        Button count = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        count.setText(Integer.toString(i));

        Button img = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

}
```

in this i get null pointer exception
anyone plz help me
 thanx in advance

Comment: it should be good to add logcat.

Comment: sir i can't load logCat img because my reputation is less then 10

Comment: can you edit your post and indicate the line the NPE occurs on?

Comment: when i click in logCat on my package name then errors at this line shows

Comment: Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  ViewTasks where Category_name = "+"'"+"cat"+"'", null);

Comment: i suspect that `mDb` is null. have you called `mDb = <db_helper>.getReadableDatabase()` before that function call???

Comment: at the top of `cursorAdapter2` you have the line `DbAdapter myAdapter = new DbAdapter(mContext);` that value assignment is passing in NULL as `mContext` doesn't yet have a value. move the assignment into the class' constructor.

Comment: i have define the query method in Adapter class when i cal Adapter.open then on the method in adater class i.e mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); error occurs

Comment: i thought you said the error occurs on the query? now it's occurring on `mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`?

Comment: sir to which assignment i move to the class constructer

Comment: this is the logCat error at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)

Comment: `DbAdapter myAdapter = new DbAdapter(mContext);` should be `DbAdapter myAdapter;` then in the constructor...after `mContext=context;` put the assignment `myAdapter = new DbAdapter(mContext);`

Comment: Sir it worked but can't get count

Comment: on the button only 0 displayed

Comment: no longer getting an exception? have you run your query in sqlite3 in the shell? perhaps there are no rows that satisfy the query.

Comment: sir there are four rows in table in which three are of the same category and one of another

Comment: one last thing i'd do if i were you is to clean up the query to use host variables. `Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT Count(*) FROM  ViewTasks where Category_name = ?", new String[] { "cat" } );`. You should verify that query in `sqlite3` to make sure that there is a matching row(s).

Comment: Sir output is still the same

Comment: then you don't have any matching rows in the DB. verify this by going into the shell and run `sqlite3 /data/data/<packageName>/databases/<dbName>.db` and run the query. see what you get.

Comment: sir i m passing to the query method the textview text as an argument in the cursorAdapter2 class

Comment: i verify sir in the Db four rows are in which three are of the same Category name and one with another category name

Comment: i believe you...and see the code. it shouldn't take a minute to run the query in `sqlite3` (you'll need to do this sooner or later anyway, might as well get used to it now).

Comment: oh! you are passing in the string "CAT" to the query. it is a variable! see my answer for correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two things. first the assignment of `DbAdapter myAdapter` should be done in the class' constructor...when mContext has a value.

```
public cursorAdapter2(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mContext=context;
    myAdapter = new DbAdapter(mContext);
}
```

secondly modify the query from....

```
Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  ViewTasks where Category_name = "+"'"+"cat"+"'", null);
```

to

```
Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT Count(*) FROM ViewTasks where Category_name = ?", new String[] { cat } );
```

you are passing in the string `"cat"` not the variable `cat`.

Comment: great! i'd appreciate it if you would ACCEPT my answer. good luck in the future.